# Custom cells not loading in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having the strangest issue; does anyone know why the below table view isn't loading my custom cells? And yes, the datasource and delegate are connected to the view controller :) I've done this before, but all of a sudden it's like something missing.

**.h**

```
@interface MyAccountViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *StorageTableView;

    NSArray *StoredItems;
    NSMutableData *data;
    }
```

**.m**

```
      - (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview

        {
            return 1;

        }

        - (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {

            return [StoredItems count];

        }

       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"StorageItemTableViewCell";

    StorageItemTableViewCell *cell = (StorageItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];



        NSDictionary *node = [StoredItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [[cell itemName] setText:[node objectForKey:@"title"]];
       [[cell itemDescrip] setText:[[[[node objectForKey:@"body"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"raw"] objectForKey:@"value"]];

    }
    return cell;
}

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return 99;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


    }
```

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done? Are the data source methods being called? What does [StoredItems count] return?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One big problem is that you only setup each cell once. You need to change your code to:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"StorageItemTableViewCell";

    StorageItemTableViewCell *cell = (StorageItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.itemName.text = [[StoredItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.itemDescrip.text = [[StoredItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];

    return cell;
}
```

You also need to make sure that `[StoredItems count]` is returning a non-zero value.

Comment: Even if StoredItems was empty, wouldn't my cells still load, just without the data (e.g. labels with default text)?

Comment: No, it `StoreItems` is empty then your table is setup with zero rows. In such a case, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never called.

Comment: Gotcha. I can't seem to find a way to NSLog StoredItems because the tableview never actually loads (e.g. the run never even gets as far as my breakpoint at StoredItems?) Is there another way to see what's in there? Sorry for the newb question lol.

Comment: Are you really sure the data source is set? If numberOfRowsInSection isn't called them the data source isn't set.

Comment: It has to be because StoredItems is empty; just removed StoredItems all together to test and make sure the custom cell was actually being called, and now they show up. Now trying to sort out why my datasource is empty... I've set the delegate & datasource to the view controller. That's correct, no?

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your custom cell for use?

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
[self.StorageTableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"StorageItemTableViewCell"];
```

Comment: You can usually put this in viewDidLoad()